# How to insert comma separated string into SQL Server table while each part in new column

Tags: php, sql-server

Example:

```
$words = 'word1,word2,word3';
```

Ouput:

```
id    value1  value2 value3
---   ------  ------ -------
1     word1   word2  word3
```

I want the data to be inserted in a single row but in different columns

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$data = '"1","1","8009","8989"';
$stmt = odbc_prepare($con," INSERT INTO stock( SiteId, DatabaseId, Code, Category) VALUES(?,?,?,?)");
$success = odbc_execute($stmt,array($data) );
odbc_close($con);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? :-)

Comment: Your title says MySQL, and your tag says SQL Server 2008. Which is it?

Comment: So explode $words on the comma to get an array of words; then you can insert them as individual words.... although why this table structure?

Comment: edit your post https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48749373/edit not including code in comments

Comment: Will there only ever be 3 words? Could there be 1? Perhaps 4, 10, more?

Comment: How does that code you have tried not do what you are saying? Your insert statement is 4 values with 4 columns.

Comment: I have tried running it ,its not inserting into the database

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use explode function

```
<?php
$words = 'word1,word2,word3';

$data_array = explode(',', $words);

    $a=$data_array[0];
    $b=$data_array[1];
    $c=$data_array[2];
    //insert Qquery here.
?>
```

Comment: Thank you ,one challenge is i have tables with +300 columns is possible to use $data_array in my insert Query without assigning each $data_array element to a variable

Comment: If you have tables with 300+ columns like this, then you have a database design problem